# Android kotlin and Room Persistences library not building

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to use Room with kotlin and nothing works it throws the following:

```
Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than - source '1.8'

The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]'
```

In my Build.Gradle class, I have the following(Out of order but all the important info is here)

```
//project build.gradle
ext {
   versions = [
        support: '25.3.1',
        dagger     : '2.11',
        arch_comp  : '1.0.0-alpha1'
    ]
}
//app build.gradle 

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"

compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.versions.arch_comp"
```

My module class

```
@Entity(tableName = "groups")
data class Group(@ColumnInfo(name = "group_name")
                 var groupName: String = "",
                 @ColumnInfo(name = "users")
                 var users :ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0

}
```

My Dao class

```
@Dao
interface GroupDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM groups")
   fun getAll() : LiveData<ArrayList<Group>>

   @Query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_name = :p0")
   fun getGroupByName(groupName: String) : Group

   //I also did this but with no succsess instade of the above
   @Query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_name = :arg0")
   fun getGroupByName(groupName: String) : Group 
}
```

Am i missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you by any chance setting your source version to 1.8. Try taking that out see if it fixes the issue

Comment: No I'm not I'm using the 1.8 that's why it's so weird

Comment: The Gradle output you've posted only contains warnings, not errors. Could please specify "nothing works" more precisely? Maybe related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17959

Comment: @GilGoldzweig As I know those error messages are not actually errors, they are warnings. Do you see anything else in "Messages" tab beside those warnings?

Comment: that's the issue the are errors it doesn't let me compile on these so called warnings because the error sais fix the warrnings

Comment: @GilGoldzweig it's strange, I've just had the same warnings plus error `Error:(1, 1) Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please see the error messages above.`, and after fixing the error it starts working without fixing any warnings.

Comment: @VasylGlodan i really don't know

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and thought that the warning was the issue.

After scrolling a bit up in the Event log I saw that my builds fails when Room checks if my SQL is good.

Please check the log, but i guess Room has hard time converting your

```
var users :ArrayList<String>
```